# SmsSubmitPdu GSMComm command is not supported by the device Wavecom modem

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

i am using GSMComm library and Wavecom modem to create simple program SMS Sender, when i press the button Send in my winform a got a message debug in my VS2010.

***The phone reports an unspecified error. This typically happens when a command is not supported by the device, a command is not valid for the current state or if a parameter is incorrect.***

this my code

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var port = "COM3"; // default port to connect modem wavecom
            var baudRate = 115200;
            var timeout = 300;
            var comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudRate, timeout);

        try
        {
            var msg = txtIsiPesan.Text;
            var phoneNumber = txtNoTujuan.Text;
            comm.Open();
            SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(msg, phoneNumber, "");
            comm.SendMessage(pdu); //debug found error here
            comm.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error");
        }

    }
```

Is this indicate that my wavecom modem didn't support to SmsSubmitPdu ?
Please suggest me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.

```
SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(msg, phoneNumber, "");
```

the third parameter should be service center number as i am using GrameenPhone it is **+8801700000600**

So i tried with

```
SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(msg, phoneNumber, "+8801700000600");
```

and successfull send sms. By the way make sure your com port is correct as mine is COM5.

```
var port = "COM5"; // default port to connect modem wavecom
            var baudRate = 115200;
            var timeout = 300;
            var comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudRate, timeout);

            try
            {
                var msg = "TESTING";
                var phoneNumber = "+8801719461643";
                comm.Open();
                SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(msg, phoneNumber, "+8801700000600");
                comm.SendMessage(pdu); //debug found error here
                comm.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error");
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your response suggest, can you know how to make auto response incoming sms in gsmcomm like gammu?

Answer (score 2):

when comm is open you can do a long polling by while loop ,read sms and delete the index of the sms msg.Add the code after **comm.Open();**

```
while(true){
 DecodedShortMessage[] messages =
     gsmCommMain.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
    foreach (var decodedShortMessage in messages)
    {
           var msgData = decodedShortMessage.Data.UserDataText;
          int indexP = decodedShortMessage.Index;
          gsmCommMain.DeleteMessage(indexP, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
          //  gsmCommMain.DeleteMessages(DeleteScope.Read, PhoneStorageType.Sim); delete all msg


       } 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when there is a short message how to get index message? because it message doesn't save in SIM CARD. `
if (obj is ShortMessage) //when the message isn't save in SIM card
{
  var msgs = (ShortMessage)obj;
  SmsPdu pdu = CommSetting.comm.DecodeReceivedMessage(msgs);
}`

Comment: use  **PhoneStorageType.Phone** instead of **PhoneStorageType.Sim**

Comment: is there any detail code sir? then i need for auto response sms sir... like gammu,.. when user sms the modem, modem auto send sms back..

Comment: That can be done after **gsmCommMain.DeleteMessage(indexP, PhoneStorageType.Sim);** send Sms to To Person you want to response `SmsSubmitPdu pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(msg, phoneNumber, "+8801700000600");
                comm.SendMessage(pdu); //Add your msg and phoneNumber`

Comment: yes, you're right,... i can use it to auto response sms... thanks ,..so helpfull