# Gsmcomm can open port but return no phone connected

Tags: c#, gsm, gsmcomm

I use GSM modem seimen to send SMS.
I use library Gsmcomm to connect to modem
Modem plug into PC by USB Serial Port

My problem is i can open port with no error:

```
GsmCommMain comm = new GsmCommMain("COM20", 19200, 300); 
comm.Open();
```

but after that i call send message it though error "no phone connected"

```
pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu("test", "0965432341", "");
comm.SendMessage(pdu);
```

I was checked in computer device management,it exits COM20
I download this source and running too but with no luck
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem-2

Anybody who faced this problem, help me fix this.

thanks

Comment: See answer two : the third parameter should be service center number  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910230/smssubmitpdu-gsmcomm-command-is-not-supported-by-the-device-wavecom-modem

Comment: Thanks @jdweng  but my situation is when i call any function of comm object, it return "No phone connected", can we  fix this ?

Comment: Then the baud rate or Com port number is wrong.  Check settings in modem that it is correct.  I think it should be 19200, no parity, 8 bit, no controls. also check device manager to see if modem is connected to port 20.

Comment: thanks you, i trying to find the right baudrate of my modem

Comment: Find the oscillator on the board.  The Frequency should be stamped on top.